# How do I convert the following c++ code into python

Tags: python, c++, vtk

everyone.I'm trying to learn VTK in python.Now I have a problem. I have no way to convert the following case into my python code, and I don't know what the parameters represent. What I've got is the polygon object, and the following code is to determine whether a given point is within the polygon range I've drawn. Source link[enter link description here](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Utilities/PointInPolygon/),The reason I can't convert is because it's in the `polygon->ComputeNormal(polygon->GetPoints()->GetNumberOfPoints(),
          static_cast<double*>(polygon->GetPoints()->GetData()->GetVoidPointer(0)), n);`,And I used python to get polygon->GetPoints()->GetData()->GetVoidPointer(0)) to get None

```
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkPoints.h>
#include <vtkPolygon.h>

int main(int, char *[])
{
  // Create the polygon
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolygon> polygon =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolygon>::New();
  polygon->GetPoints()->InsertNextPoint(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  polygon->GetPoints()->InsertNextPoint(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  polygon->GetPoints()->InsertNextPoint(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  polygon->GetPoints()->InsertNextPoint(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

  double testIn[3] = {0.5, 0.5, 0.0};
  double testOut[3] = {2.0, 0.5, 0.0};

  double n[3];
  polygon->ComputeNormal(polygon->GetPoints()->GetNumberOfPoints(),
          static_cast<double*>(polygon->GetPoints()->GetData()->GetVoidPointer(0)), n);

  double bounds[6];
  polygon->GetPoints()->GetBounds(bounds);

  std::cout << "testIn in polygon? " << polygon->PointInPolygon(testIn,
      polygon->GetPoints()->GetNumberOfPoints(), static_cast<double*>(
      polygon->GetPoints()->GetData()->GetVoidPointer(0)), bounds, n) << std::endl;

  std::cout << "testOut in polygon? " << polygon->PointInPolygon(testOut,
      polygon->GetPoints()->GetNumberOfPoints(), static_cast<double*>(
      polygon->GetPoints()->GetData()->GetVoidPointer(0)), bounds, n) << std::endl;

  /*
  std::cout << "New functions:" << std::endl;

  std::cout << "testIn in polygon? " << polygon->PointInPolygon(testIn) << std::endl;

  std::cout << "testOut in polygon? " << polygon->PointInPolygon(testOut) << std::endl;
  */
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```
  /**
   * Determine whether point is inside polygon. Function uses ray-casting
   * to determine if point is inside polygon. Works for arbitrary polygon shape
   * (e.g., non-convex). Returns 0 if point is not in polygon; 1 if it is.
   * Can also return -1 to indicate degenerate polygon.
   */
  static int PointInPolygon(double x[3], int numPts, double *pts,
                            double bounds[6], double n[3]);
```

Comment: This is not a question that you can ask. That means you need someone to do it for you instead of helping. You should state what you have tried, and where you are stuck. Recall this is a platform to obtain help. Not for the project to be fully solved. You should rather consider paying someone to convert the code completely from c++ to python

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Maybe I put it in the wrong way,I don't need you to turn it all into python, I'm just doing `polygon->ComputeNormal(polygon->GetPoints()->GetNumberOfPoints(),
Static_cast < > double * (polygon - > GetPoints () - > GetData () - > GetVoidPointer (0)), n);`I don't understand this line of code, and I don't know how to turn it into python, and I put out all the code just to make it easy for you to understand, because I haven't seen this parameter mode in python, and I've looked up a lot of stuff that doesn't work, and all I need is an idea, right

Comment: Are you just trying to come up with Python code that does the same functionality (i.e. can determine if a point is inside a polygon)?  If so, Python already has a library for creating points and polygons and determining if tis inside a polygon.  Wouldn't this be easier to use rather than trying to convert the C code?

Comment: Could you please tell me what this library is? Thank you very much. I can use this library for reference and then convert myself.

Comment: You mention not being aware of what the parameters represent.  Are you aware of the [function signatures for computeNormal](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolygon.html#af12ee87e9f125b890ae0e6cb4273b2c2), plus [inheritance diagram](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolygon.html)

Comment: Regarding the library I was referring to Shapely.  [Example of using Shapely](https://streamhacker.com/2010/03/23/python-point-in-polygon-shapely/#:~:text=Shapely%20is%20an%20offshoot%20of,in%2Dpolygon%20calculations%20very%20easy.) to determine if a point is inside a polygon.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll give it a try.I've looked at the source code for VTK, but it looks like he just told me what the function does, doesn't say anything about the parameters, I just guess what the parameters might be and then I pass it the corresponding parameters,Maybe it is my poor English level that makes it difficult for me to learn it.

Comment: Was my [signature for computeNormal](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolygon.html#af12ee87e9f125b890ae0e6cb4273b2c2) helpful in understanding the parameters?  You can click on the them for more detail.

Comment: The line you wrote is a method of the class vktPolygon. in python, that function will be run as `polygon.ComputeNormal(polygon.GetPoints().GetNumberOfPoints(), polygon. GetPoints ().GetData().GetVoidPointer (0), n)` The issue is you have to even convert the headers that you have if they are already not available in Pyton. If it was converting python to c++, that would have been easy. Probably you should consider running the c++ code from python using boost

Comment: thanks, I've tried this before, this is not available, it will prompt `arguments do not match any overloaded methods`。Thank you all the same。

Comment: DarrylG，Yes, it helped me a lot